# Jolt transform expand dot as a JSON Object

Tags: json, jolt

Is there a way in Jolt to convert a dot operator in JSON value to a nested JSON object while transforming the input ?

For example in the below json I would like target_property of id=2 to be converted to a json object as shown in the expected O/P. Any help is appreciated

**Input:**

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "email": "Test",
  "form_id": "123",
  "field_list": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "Test Subject",
      "is_custom_field": false,
      "target_property": "subject"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "Test Description",
      "is_custom_field": false,
      "target_property": "comment.body"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Jolt Transform tried**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "form_id": "ticket.ticket_form_id",
      "name": "ticket.requester.name",
      "email": "ticket.requester.email",
      "field_list": {
        "*": {
          "is_custom_field": {
            "true": {
              "@(2,target_property)": "ticket.custom_fields[&3].id",
              "@(2,value)": "ticket.custom_fields[&3].value"
            },
            "*": {
              "@(2,value)": "ticket.@(3,target_property)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Current Output**

```
{
  "ticket" : {
    "ticket_form_id" : "123",
    "requester" : {
      "name" : "Test",
      "email" : "Test"
    },
    "subject" : "Test Subject",
    "comment.body" : "Test Description"
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```json
{
  "ticket": {
    "ticket_form_id": "123",
    "requester": {
      "name": "Test",
      "email": "Test"
    },
    "subject": "Test Subject",
    "comment": {
      "body": "Test Description"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another **shift** transformation spec such that

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "*": "&1.&",
      "*.*": "&1.&(0,1).&(0,2)"
    }
  }
}
```

where

- `"*.*"` represents the attributes having a dot within them. the zeroes
  within `&(0,..)` expressions stand for *the current level*
- **1**,**2** as second arguments of them represent the first and the second pieces of the splitted keys (in this case **`comment.body`**)
  respectively.